# dynamically add/remove rows in an iOS View (like rules in Mail)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, tableview, rows

I am working on an application that has a view in which the opening hours of a store need to be configured.

So there is a list with all days of the week:
- Monday    from [10:00] to [12:00] (-) (+)
- Tuesday   from [10:00] to [12:00] (-) (+)
                    from [14:00] to [18:00] (-) (+)
- Wednesday (+)
- Thursday  (+)
- Friday from [10:00] to [18:00] (-) (+)
- Saturday  (+)
- Sunday    (+)

So there can be multiple opening hours per day. Pressing the (-) button removes the line, and pressing (+) adds a line.

I would like to implement this like the rules configurations in Mail.
(cannot provide screenshots yet, as this my first question)

I assume this could be implemented like a tableview, where each day has a UITableView and every row is an interval of opening time. But I am not sure.
If it would be that way, how can I dynamically resize the table view to just show the necessary rows? And how do I then rearrange the layout so there is no overlapping?

Even better would be a more simplistic approach, or a framework that care of something similar as that.

Thank you very much already for your help!

Comment: There are some UI Guidelines from apple, i am not sure this nested tableview will be allowed in ios. For Mac OS, I have this sort of code in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Utilising a UITableView is certainly a good approach in my opinion. In order to manage rows of varying size, a good technique would be to create a static method for the UITableViewCell class that returns a CGFloat height given the content the cell is supposed to display. For example, if the cell needs to display some text, you would create a method similar to this one:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellWithText:(NSString *)text
```

Keep in mind that this information needs to be passed via the UITableViewDelegate's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. The beauty of this technique is that you don't actually need to create the UITableViewCell instance to determine it's height - this is calculated and passed to the TableView once it's needed, regardless of whether the instance is already allocated or not.

Hope this gives you a prod in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

There are apple delegate methods that provide ur a functionality to edit table view with some delegate methods.

Also u can delete your row and add new row in table. But remember that while adding or deleting a row, u must update ur data source each time.

Its hard to explain all these methods here. But there are some sample projects which have all these functionality already implemented which u want .

Check Sample project for editing table View style [here Sample Code](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/)

another sample code for this is [sample project 2](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-delete-data-from-tableview-in-iphone/)

I hope this will helps u and resolves ur peoblem.